# jQuery margin animation only runs once

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, margin

I used the jQuery animation from [this](https://css-tricks.com/full-jquery-animations/) page.

**And this is my code:**

```
/** ANIMATE FRONTPAGE ELEMENT **/
$(".frontpage-element-wrap").hover(function(){
    if (!$('.scroll-fade-in-2', this).hasClass('animated')) {
        $('.scroll-fade-in-2', this).dequeue().stop().animate({ 'margin-left': "0px" });
    }
}, function() {
    $('.scroll-fade-in-2', this).addClass('animated').animate({ 'margin-left': "60px" }, "normal", "linear", function() {
        $('.scroll-fade-in-2', this).removeClass('animated').dequeue();
    });
});
```

The original CSS of `.scroll-fade-in-2` is just `margin-left: 60px;`

How come this only runs as planned once, and then the next time I hover, its not working.

Comment: can you add a fiddle?

Comment: I've added jQuery to your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/94teLu64/). The code seems to work?

Comment: @Teemu Still only runs once... not twice as I want it to. UPDATE: If I select another field in fiddle, it runs properly, however if I dont select anything else. It runs only once.

Comment: Please explain in more details, what you expect your code to do, and what it does instead? I can see (FF44) the margin resizing to 0px on hover, and getting back to 60px when moving mouse out any of the divs, no matter where the cursor end up, or how many times a div is hovered.

Comment: @teemu see website provided. I have testet in firefox and safari, same result. The phone are simply just animating ONCE, before the hover mechanism is "invalid".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Suggest you to use CSS instead of jQuery, because by css you can have more better animation and it could be more optimized.
This is your example with css:
https://jsfiddle.net/linkers/kh7qhx2g/4/

```
#frontpage-element-wrap{
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #aeaeae;
}
.scroll-fade-in-2{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-left: 60px;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
#frontpage-element-wrap:hover .scroll-fade-in-2{
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Of course, I didn't think I could do it this easily :) Thanks! :)